# decimal.TryParse() drops leading "1"

Tags: .net

Short and sweet version:

On one machine out of around a hundred test machines decimal.TryParse() is converting "1.01" to 0.01

---

Okay, this is going to sound crazy but bear with me...

We have a client applications that communicates with a webservice through JSON, and that service returns a decimal value as a string so we store it as a string in our model object:

```
[DataMember(Name = "value")]
public string Value { get; set; }
```

When we display that value on screen it is formatted to a specific number of decimal places. So the process we use is string -> decimal then decimal -> string.

The application is currently undergoing final testing and is running on more than 100 machines, where this all works fine. However on *one* machine if the decimal value has a leading '1' then it is replaced by a zero. I added simple logging to the code so it looks like this:

```
Log("Original string value: {0}", value);
decimal val;
if (decimal.TryParse(value, out val))
{
    Log("Parsed decimal value: {0}", val);
    string output = val.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
    Log("Formatted string value: {0}", output);
    return output;
}
```

On my machine - any every other client machine - the logfile output is:

> - Original string value: 1.010000
> - Parsed decimal value: 1.010000
> - Formatted string value: 1.01

On the defective machine the output is:

> - Original string value: 1.010000
> - Parsed decimal value: 0.010000
> - Formatted string value: 0.01

So it would appear that the decimal.TryParse method is at fault.

Things we've tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling the client application
- Uninstalling and reinstalling .net 3.5 sp1
- Comparing the defective machine's regional settings for numbers (using English (United Kingdom)) to those of a working machine - no differences.

Has anyone seen anything like this or has any suggestions? I'm quickly running out of ideas...

---

While I was typing this some more info came in: Passing a string value of "10000" to Convert.ToInt32() returns 0, so that also seems to drop the leading 1.

---

Further tests based on comments:

- 1.01 -> 0.01
- 111.01 -> 11.01
- 123.01 -> 23.01
- 231.01 -> 231.01
- 01.01 -> 1.01

So it would appear that it only affects 1s and only if they are the first character of the string. Very odd, but at least it's consistent.

Comment: Weird. What happens with other digits like "123" or "321"?

Comment: Bad RAM in the machine?  Have you tried running something like memtest86?

Comment: This is a really bad idea, but if you pre-pad with a zero...?

Comment: What is the result when you try 2.010000 or 9.010000 as input?

Comment: @hans, @spender, @prutswonder - I've updated the question with some more tests.

Comment: Is it also consistent across different .Net versions (2.0 & 3.5) and does `decimal.Parse()` give the same results?

Comment: @Prutswonder - I just wrote a console application that does nothing but convert strings to decimals with TryParse() and built it for 3.5 and 2.0. The results were the same, so it isn't anything to do with our client application and isn't version specific...

Comment: Take the machine out to the parking lot and back over it with your car.  Several times, to make sure.  Problem solved.

Comment: Take Reflector disassemble the Decimal.TryParse and step through int, to see what is going on.

Comment: Could you please share if you ever figure out what caused this? This cal be useful to other people with this issue, and would make a great practical joke.

Comment: @Kobi - Unfortunately, since we are a couple of weeks away from release and we have proven that it is a fault with his machine and not the software that's all I have time for on this. I'd like to know as well, but my guess it that something in the custom software we run (from many companies built over many years) did something stupid. I can say that it *isn't* in that registry entry though, so it must be quite low level...

Comment: Ok, cool. But shame, it's an exotic bug. Good luck!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am able to reproduce your results.
Consider:

```
public NumberFormatInfo OneIsPositiveSignFormat()
{
    NumberFormatInfo custom = new NumberFormatInfo();
    custom.PositiveSign = "1";
    return custom;
}
```

And then:

```
if (decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Number, OneIsPositiveSignFormat(), out val))
```

The thing is: Regional Settings does not show you the current **positive sign**, and mainly: you did not set the culture when parsing the number.

The value may come from various locations: It may have come from the registry as the system defaults, or the defaults could have been set by code:

```
CultureInfo customCulture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
customCulture.NumberFormat = OneIsPositiveSignFormat();
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
```

Comment: Interesting answer, but it begs the question that if Regional Settings doesn't allow you to set the positive sign, and the OP's regional settings are the same as the other machines, how could the positive sign have been changed?  I'm not disagreeing with you, it fits the examples perfectly, I'm just curious.

Comment: And we have a winner! Just ran the following code on his machine: Console.WriteLine(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.PositiveSign); and it outputs "1". Now, just need to figure out how to change this back...

Comment: I bet it was a third party program that did this. What a monstrosity.

Comment: Happy to help. I can't find a registry setting for this (should be on `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International` ), but maybe it can be added.

Answer (score -1):

see how the regional settings are set for this computer it might be that "." is set as thousand separator not as decimal separator. Try using Decimal.TryParse (String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, out Decimal val) and pass NumberFormatInfo created with decimal separator "."

Comment: OP has already said there are no differences in the regional settings - plus if 1.000 was input when `.` was a thousand separator, it would give 1000, not 0.